# I'm getting UnityException Texture is not readable. Ho should I handle it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't understand this exception and what to do to fix it.

The exception is on line 38 :

```
pixels = origTex.GetPixels();
```

The full exception message :

UnityException: Texture 'screen_1920x1080_2021-07-09_14-08-00' is not readable, the texture memory can not be accessed from scripts. You can make the texture readable in the Texture Import Settings.

I'm not sure how to handle it.
It wasn't before this is the first time I'm getting this exception.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class RawImagePixelsChange : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Create a blank RawImage and drag this script onto it

    // NOTE: Unless you create a new texture from the image (instead of using it directly),
    // changes will alter the asset itself!
    // Textures must be type 2D/UI and have Read/Write enabled

    // Unity docs say GetPixels32 etc. is faster, but I wasn't able to get the modifyPixels() to work...
    // colors kept wrapping around 255, even with clamps (?)

    RawImage myImage; // texture will be assigned in code, but can assign in Inspector to see in Editor

    public Texture2D origTex; // drag texture to slot in Inspector
    public Texture2D newTex; // leave blank, will be created in code

    public float lightenAmount = 0.1f;

    Color[] pixels;

    void Start()
    {
        var texture = GetComponent<RawImage>().texture;
        origTex = texture as Texture2D;

        myImage = GetComponent<RawImage>();

        // Prints the float equivalent color at pixel (50,50). Note the texture origin is lower left!
        //print("pixel 50, 50 = " + origTex.GetPixel(50, 50));

        if (texture != null && origTex != null)
        {
            pixels = origTex.GetPixels();

            newTex = new Texture2D(origTex.width, origTex.height);

            newTex.SetPixels(pixels);
            newTex.Apply();
            myImage.texture = newTex;
        }
    }

    public void modifyPixels(float lightenAmount) // Press "P" to change pixel colors by lightenAmount
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i++)
        {
            pixels[i].r += lightenAmount;
            if (pixels[i].r > 1) pixels[i].r = 1;
            if (pixels[i].r < 0) pixels[i].r = 0;
            pixels[i].g += lightenAmount;
            if (pixels[i].g > 1) pixels[i].g = 1;
            if (pixels[i].g < 0) pixels[i].g = 0;
            pixels[i].b += lightenAmount;
            if (pixels[i].b > 1) pixels[i].b = 1;
            if (pixels[i].b < 0) pixels[i].b = 0;
        }
        newTex.SetPixels(pixels);
        newTex.Apply();
    }
    public void restorePixels() // Press "O" (letter O) to restore original texture/image
    {
        pixels = origTex.GetPixels();
        newTex.SetPixels(pixels);
        newTex.Apply();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
        {
            modifyPixels(lightenAmount);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
        {
            restorePixels();
        }
    }

    public float Amount()
    {
        return lightenAmount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Click your image and in the inspector on that image check the "Read/Write Enabled" box on Advanced and then click Apply.

Answer (score 8):

Make it Read/Write Enabled via the [Import Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TextureTypes.html#Default) in the Inspector.

> **Read/Write Enabled**
>
> Enable this property to access the Texture data from scripts using Texture2D.SetPixels, Texture2D.GetPixels and other Texture2D methods. Internally, Unity uses a copy of the Texture data for script access, which doubles the amount of memory required for the Texture. This property is therefore disabled by default, and you should enable it only if you require script access. For more information, see Texture2D.

[image]